# Fetching Complete Data from a JMeter test

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm using JMeter 4.0 and I see we can get the results in the csv and HTML file by using the below command -

```
jmeter.bat -n -t C:/Users/dev/Desktop/Testscript.jmx -JUsers=10 -Jdelay=3 -JDuration=10 -l C:/Users/dev/Desktop/output.csv -e -o C:/Users/dev/Desktop/htmlresults.html
```

When I check the csv file, i only see the below metrics but in the HTML file, a whole lot of metrics have been shown.

CSV File -

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
```

In the HTML file, I am able to see the below details which are not shown in csv file.
[image]

[image]

Is it possible to get all these details as well like - 90th, 95th, 99 percentile, threads, running Vusers, elapsed time, throughput, etc ? *Where does JMeter store all these values to frame a HTML file* as it is only displaying only a certain metrics in csv file.

Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

These values are being [**calculated**](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) from the metrics which are stored in the CSV file.

If you want to get the data in CSV form for any reason you can use [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which can generate different types of reports and charts out of .jtl results file.

You can install the command-line tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I have downloaded the plugin. How should I run this if I need to get all the important parameters at once, like HitsPerSecond, BytesThroughputOverTime, ResponseTimesOverTime, etc. I am not clear on the command `JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime`. I have script called test.jxm and i am trying `jmeter.bat -n -t C:/Users/dev/Desktop/Testscript.jmx -JUsers=10 -Jdelay=3 -JDuration=10 -l C:/Users/dev/Desktop/output.csv` but still get the old details only. kindly clarify.